# conditional with no leading zeros in decimal number using regular expression

Tags: regex

Below is my regular expression I am working with

`^\d+\.?((25)|(5)|(75)|0+)?$` which should be allowing numbers like

`0010`,`10.0`,`0.0`,`0`,`0.25`,`1.0`,`22`,`1.5`,`11.25`,`23.75`,`22.000` etc.

I don't want to allow like
`0017.5`,`0010.0` etc with leading `0`s in decimal numbers.

How can I make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a range to the starting number instead of allowing any number and allow 0 or more numbers after that number but before the comma. Remove the `?..?` quantifier because you want to make sure it is a decimal number. To account for whole numbers add `|(\d+)`. And to account for numbers between 0 and 1, add `([0]\.((25)|(5)|(75)|0+))` This becomes:

`^(([0]\.((25)|(5)|(75)|0+))|([1-9]\d*\.((25)|(5)|(75)|0+))|(\d+))$`

Comment: `^(([1-9]\d*\.((25)|(5)|(75)|0+))|(\d+))$` [does not match numbers between 1 and 0, and `0.0`](https://regex101.com/r/D7vmoS/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true, fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you may use lookaheads in the regex pattern, you may use

```
^(?!0+[1-9]\d*\.\d)\d+(?:\.(?:[27]?5|0+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XwyRkl/1). The `(?!0+[1-9]\d*\.\d)` negative lookahead will fail the match if the strings starts with one or more zeros and the number is itself a number with a fractional part.

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0+[1-9]\d*\.\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately at the start of the string, there is

  - `0+` - one or more `0` chars
  - `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d`  - a digit
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.(?:[27]?5|0+))?` - an optional string that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:[27]?5|0+)` - `2` or `7` (optionally) and then `5`, or one or more `0` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: You're still missing the case for numbers between 0-1 with leading zero's.

Comment: @SBylemans You may remove your above comment as  "numbers between 0-1 with leading zero's" are matched well, you may [see how `0.25` or `0.0` are matched here](https://regex101.com/r/XwyRkl/1).

Comment: [Numbers between 0 and 1 with multiple leading zero's are also matched](https://regex101.com/r/XwyRkl/2) Such as `000.25`

Comment: @SBylemans That case is not covered in the original post. If the values like `000.25` should not be matched, [`^(?!(?:0{2,}|0+[1-9]\d*)\.\d)\d+(?:\.(?:[27]?5|0+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XwyRkl/3) will do the job.